# Android Google Analytics connection to service failed 1

Tags: android, google-analytics

I tried to implement the google analytics on my Android app with the following code onCreate but it seems nothing appear in Google Analytics (Real-time) mode and I checked the GAV2 Catlog with following:

Connection to service failed 1

No campaign found

bindService return false.......

NO idea ?!!!!!! My iphone app version work with google analytics but android not work yet...

Anyone give me hints.

Thanks.

```
  Context mCtx = this; // Get current context.
  GoogleAnalytics myInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
  myInstance.setDebug(true);
  Tracker myNewTracker = myInstance.getTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-1"); // A new tracking ID.
  myNewTracker.trackView("/app_launched");
```

Comment: I have the same error. As I understand - GA android lib can't connect to server. Maybe server refuses connection, but why?.. I have added new app profile to GA two days ago, but still nothing tracks...